# reveal.js - Remote control

Tags: javascript, reveal.js

In the reveal.js Github says that there's a way to activate the a remote control for the presentation using a touch device, without using third party scripts.

This is:

```
Reveal.initialize({
    dependencies: [ 
        // Remote control your reveal.js presentation using a touch device
        { src: 'plugin/remotes/remotes.js', async: true }
    ]
});
```

I have put that code but i don't get what to do next for it to work using my phone.

I know there's a way to do this via node.js, but my server doesn't support that.

I'll appreciate any help.
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like a generic support from the `reveal.js` side.

Follow steps from here [remot.io](http://remot.io/) for concrete example on how to make it work.

Comment: Looks like the link to remot.io is broken.